# How can I enable compiler warnings in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The reason that I ask this question is this link below:
*[Why can this function return a C++ int reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899006/why-can-this-function-return-a-c-int-reference)*

It seems that the compiler is bad at reporting mistakes such as: `return` a value from a function.

So I want to activate them in Visual Studio 2019, but it did not work after I set it (restart IDE) like below:

[image]

Comment: The combination of flags you want is `/W4 /permissive-` see live: https://godbolt.org/z/T8BufA  .  Note that `/Wall` will produce too many messages include ones from the standard headers.  I currently don't have access to MSVS confirm where in the GUI the settings are.

Comment: Returning reference to temporary is reported even with  `/W1`, it is not clear how you managed not to get it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151908/enable-a-single-warning-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could try to use the following method to enable warnings that are off by default:

1,#pragma warning(default : warning_number )
The specified warning (warning_number) is enabled at its default level. Documentation for the warning contains the default level of the warning.

2,#pragma warning( warning_level : warning_number )
The specified warning (warning_number) is enabled at the specified level (warning_level).

3,/Wall
/Wall enables all warnings that are off by default. If you use this option, you can turn off individual warnings by using the /wd option.

4,/wLnnnn
This option enables warning nnnn at level L.

For more details anbout warning level, I suggest you could refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2019