# disabling warnings in external headers C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, import, header-files, suppress-warnings

I have been tasked with disabling warnings in external headers "##include" and i have read a very useful tutorial named "Broken Warnings Theory" however the tutorial leaves out how to use supplied examples, so my question is:

Where in Visual Studio do i apply the following syntax?
I assume it in the project properties somewhere but i have been unable to find any obvious place i should be applying it too.

```
cl.exe /experimental:external /external:I some_lib_dir /external:W0 /W4 my_prog.cpp
```

[Broken warnings theory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/broken-warnings-theory/)

Comment: I would try C++/Command Line/Additional Options.

Comment: You mentioned `#import` instead of `#include`?

Comment: Consider also surrounding the relevant #include(s) with suitable `#pragma warning` statements, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2019

Comment: In the screenshot from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900260/how-can-i-enable-compiler-warnings-in-visual-studio-2019) you see the dialog to set various compiler parameters. I believe what you're looking for is the the _Command Line_ section in the end of the opened tree view. I cannot prove myself, because I don't have a VS installaiton at hand ATM.

Comment: @Paul It looks like the OP already had found what they want, but just miss to see where to add these cli parameters in the VS configuation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could open `win+R->CMD` and input `cl`. Then you could apply the syntax.

[image]

Also, you may need to set the environment variables.
Add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe` in `System varibles->Path`.